# Can't pause in react native video

Tags: react-native

**I want to play an audio file, But it's playing automaticaly and I can't pause That.**

How Can I Fix That?
That Must be Paused at the begin
**My Code:**

```
import Video from 'react-native-video';

export default class Android extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      paused: true,
    }
  }

  video: Video;

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.welcome}>
          Welcome to React Native!
        </Text>
        <Text style={styles.instructions}>
          To get started, edit index.ios.js
        </Text>
        <Text style={styles.instructions}>
          Press Cmd+R to reload,{'\n'}
          Cmd+D or shake for dev menu
        </Text>
        <Video
          ref={(ref: Video) => { this.video = ref }}
          source={{ uri: "http://s3.picofile.com/d/7376893331/8b7bc5b4-4b5e-47c4-96dd-b0c13fd18157/Sara_Diba_Delbare_Man.mp3", mainVer: 1, patchVer: 0 }}
          paused={this.state.paused}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There's currently a bug in `react-native-video` where the `pause` flag is ignored when the component is first loaded. You have to change `pause` AFTER the component has loaded.

First, make sure your `this.state.pause = false`. Then:

```
<Video
  paused={this.state.paused}
  onLoad={() => {
    this.setState({
      paused: true
    });
  }}
</Video>
```

Context: https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-video/issues/494#issuecomment-281853423

Comment: Solved. Thank you

Answer (score -2):

Use ref attribute to create a link to the video and using that reference we can able to use video controls on the video component

Try this code,

```
import React from "react";
class VideoDemo extends React.Component {
  
  getVideo = elem => {
    this.video = elem
  }

  playVideo = () => {
    // You can use the play method as normal on your video ref
    this.video.play()
  };

  pauseVideo = () => {
    // Pause as well
    this.video.pause();
  };

  render = () => {
    return (
      <div>
        <video
          ref={this.getVideo}
          src="http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4"
          type="video/mp4"
        />

        <div>
          <button onClick={this.playVideo}>
            Play!
          </button>
          <button onClick={this.pauseVideo}>
            Pause!
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  };
}

export default VideoDemo;
```