# How to make play and pause the video in react-native?

Tags: react-native

i am uploading the video from my gallery , in this case video is automatically playing but i want to control the video using play and pause button and also how to delete the uploaded file. here i am using image picker from expo.

This is my code which plays automatically

```
  selectVideo = async () => {
            let result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
               mediaTypes:"Videos"
            });
              if (!result.cancelled) {
                this.setState({ video: result.uri });
              }
          };
    render(){
return(
<Avatar xlarge rounded source={require('../../../assets/arrows.png')} onPress={this.selectVideo.bind(this)}/>
    {video &&
         <Video
                  source={{ uri: video }}
                  rate={1.0}
                  volume={1.0}
                  isMuted={false}
                  resizeMode="cover"
                  shouldPlay
                  isLooping
                  style={{ width:100, height:100 }}
                />
    }
```

Comment: [might be a help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45932478/cant-pause-in-react-native-video) check this post

Comment: @mae tanaka i tried but its not working on expo  imagepicker

Answer (score 0):

WELL,i have solved this problem.i have installed **expo-video-player**

command: npm install expo-video-player.

Answer (score -1):

use pause prop to control video play and pause

```
 handleClick=()=>{
  cosnt {isPause} =this.state;
  this.setState({isPause:!isPause})
  }
  render(){
 return{
  const {isPause}=this.state;
   <VideoPlayer
    source={source}
    ref={(ref) => {
      this.player = ref;
    }}
    paused={isPause}
    onBuffer={this.onBuffer}
    onEnd={this.onEnd}
    allowsExternalPlayback={true}
    onError={this.videoError}
    width={width}
    height={height}
  />
  {isPause && <IconWrapper onPress={this.handleClick}/>}
   }}
```

Comment: will it support image picker from expo ?